# mill client.fastOpt: client.scalaJSLinkerClasspath scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.String)

Tags: scala, scala.js, mill

I want to run a *ScalaJS* module with ***mill*** Build Tool.

When running `mill client.fastOpt` I get:

```
[6/73] client.scalaJSLinkerClasspath 
1 targets failed
client.scalaJSLinkerClasspath scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.String)
    mill.scalajslib.ScalaJSModule.$anonfun$scalaJSLinkerClasspath$2(ScalaJSModule.scala:38)
    mill.define.ApplyerGenerated.$anonfun$zipMap$7(ApplicativeGenerated.scala:17)
    mill.define.Task$MappedDest.evaluate(Task.scala:365)
```

My `build.sc` is:

```
trait BaseJsModule extends ScalaJSModule {
  val scalaJSVersion = "1.0.1"
  val scalaVersion = "2.13.1"
}

object client extends BaseJsModule {
  override def moduleDeps = Seq(shared)
  override def mainClass = Some("pme123.camunda.boot.client.HelloClient")
}

object shared extends BaseJsModule
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted buildfile looks ok. You're probably using a too old mill version? Support for ScalaJS 1.0.0+ was added in mill 0.6.1.

Please note, that you can create a file `.mill-version` with the content `0.6.1` to automatically download and use mill 0.6.1.